# Erro na conexão com banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Bom dia! 
Estou com um painel em php e o mesmo não está fazendo conexão com a DB.
Qualquer senha que eu digite, da senha ou usuário incorreto.[image: Como na imagem]

Segue o trecho do código que faz a conexão:

```
<?php
session_start();
$usuariot = $_POST['usuario'];
$senhat = $_POST['senha']; 
include "conexao.php";

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$usuariot' AND senha='$senhat' LIMIT 1");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(empty($resultado)){
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header ("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

E em baixo o trecho do código que faz a conexão ao banco de dados:

```
<?php
$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Erro na conexão");
mysqli_select_db($conectar, "painel_admin");
?>
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Lembra que comentei ontem na outra pergunta? no `mysqli_query()` você precisa passar a conexão como primeiro argumento sempre.

Comment: Você quer dizer assim:  $result = mysqli_query("localhost","SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$usuariot' AND senha='$senhat' LIMIT 1");

Comment: Assim: `mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM usu....").`

Comment: Obrigado rray! Deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo

Conexão

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
```

SEU SELECT

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$usuariot' AND senha='$senhat' LIMIT 1";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if(empty($resultado)){
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header ("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: Agora deu certo! muito obrigado a todos!

Comment: @PedroRibeiro Caso a resposta tenha te ajudado, poderia marcar como resolvido e dar +1

Comment: já coloquei Rafael, porém sou novo mebro, ai não aparece.